# parameter mismatch error in map insert

Tags: c++, dictionary, stdmap

I'm Javaer for many years and a newbie in C++. Recently I need to work on a C++ project, but experience some unpleasant issues when using C++, one of them is the `std:map`.

I'm trying to insert a key-value pair into a map function.

`map[key]=value` or `map.emplace(key,value)` works fine, but `map.insert` gives me [compilation error]([image: error]), which I'm totally lost. Can someone helps?

```
class mystructure{
private:
    int value;
public:
    mystructure(int v){
        value=v;
    }
    void print(){
        std::cout<<value<<std::endl;
    }
    std::string get_Value(){
        return std::to_string(value);
    }
};

int main(void) {

    std::map<std::string, mystructure> mymap;
    std::vector<mystructure> v = std::vector<mystructure>();
    v.push_back(*(new mystructure(17)));
    v.push_back(*(new mystructure(12)));
    v.push_back(*(new mystructure(23)));
    for (int i=0;i<v.size();i++) {
        mystructure temp=v.at(i);
        mymap.insert(temp.get_Value(),temp);//compilation error
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: `*(new mystructure(17)))`  C++ is not Java.  You are creating a memory leak here.  The `new` in Java is not the same thing as `new` in C++.  Use value types, not pointers.  `v.push_back(mystructure(17));`

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie you are right, thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Because [`std::map::insert`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/map/insert) accepts `std::map::value_type` (i.e. `std::pair<const Key, T>`) as its parameter.

You could use:

```
mymap.insert(std::pair<const std::string, mystructure>(temp.get_Value(), temp));
```

or

```
mymap.insert(std::make_pair(temp.get_Value(), temp));
```

or

```
mymap.insert({temp.get_Value(), temp});
```

<kbd>[LIVE](http://rextester.com/YNMBS83780)</kbd>

Comment: @ShuhaoZhangtony What's the error message? I tried it [here](http://rextester.com/JOELS2596).

Comment: I think I probably found a bug in CLion: after I follow your suggestion, it still highlights error, but it compiles...

Comment: @ShuhaoZhangtony Always refer to your *real* compiler errors.  Those highlighting tools and "squiggly line utilities" are not 100% correct.

Comment: @ShuhaoZhangtony Yes, there might be something wrong with IDE. Anyway, the compilation result matters in the end.